# Issue in rotate camera during initial loading of 3d Object in threejs

Tags: three.js

I have to rotate the camera during initial loading of object in three js.
So can anyone help me in which way i have to do that.Can i use Perspective Camera for this ?
for reference
https://theyearofgreta.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to tween the camera movement on the initial load of the object.

```
new TWEEN.Tween(currentPosition)
.to(targetPosition, 2000)
.onUpdate(function () {
    camera.position.set(...currentPosition);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
});
```

I made a simple example to showcase the movement:
https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/ZEygVNy

Basics of using tween for three.js animations:
http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bro...not able to open the codepan example (Error 502
Bad gateway)

Comment: Codepen is down. Could try in a while.
https://twitter.com/search?q=codepen&src=typed_query&f=live